# Malwarebytes stuck at `com.baidu.appstore`, which I'm unable to find in Android

Tags: file-management

I tried malware apps and lookout ad network. The malwarebytes stucked at `com.baidu.appstore` which I can't find  in file explorer when I connect the Android to PC. There is no such app. The application also often crash.

There is one directory in `/android/com.baidu.appstore`. I have deleted that directory but problem didn't go away.

What should I do?

I suspect that I am using Zend 2 which uses Chinese ROM and is refurbished for international market.

Comment: You won't be able to see this file unless your device is rooted. Its location is most likely something like `/data/apps/com.baidu.appstore.apk` (on internal storage, which is *not* exported to your PC) – and everything below `/data` requires elevated privileges to be seen. The directory you've deleted is probably located on your SD card; it holds nothing but data from the corresponding app.

Comment: @Izzy would she be able to set USB connection charge only, then search using ADB?

Comment: @HasH_BrowN Depends on how you define "search": using `adb shell` with `ls` won't work (for the same reasons). `adb uninstall com.baidu.appstore` on the other hand would work, provided it's not a system app (which it most likely is). Afraid the scanner found the Baidu SDK in that app, which lately hit the press containing malware.

Comment: I suspected the hard drive crash